# Java - Escape quotes in style attribute

Tags: java, html, decode, decoding

In a Java application I have HTML, as a String, that looks like this:

```
<DIV STYLE=&quot;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;&quot;>
```

And I wish to decode the encoded quotes so that it is correctly displayed on the page. The problem is that conventional `StringEscapeUtils` escape methods will decode each quote as a double quote, resulting in HTML like this:

```
<DIV STYLE="font-family:"Times New Roman"">
```

Which will not correctly render on the page. The desired result is for the HTML to look like this:

```
<DIV STYLE='font-family:"Times New Roman"'>
```

I can algorithmically examine the string to replace the encoded quotes to what I  want but is there a dedicated method to correctly decode quotes for such a String?

Comment: think about your design. You should not a have such Information in your Java code. It should be in css or the HTML page

Comment: This is at a point where that particular bit of information is being parsed before being saved. I don't have any control over the structure of the HTML.

Comment: The problem is that the string is incorrectly *en*coded. That can't be fixed in the decoding (it's not deterministically decodable), you need to fix the encoding process.

Comment: Just what @ErwinBolwidt said, fix the encoding process, or slap the one providing you with this incorrectly encoded HTML. But *if* you want to convert your string into valid HTML, you can grab a kind of tokenizer and somehow determine whether quotes are inside other quotes, but then again, you would be fixing problems caused by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If it is defined in your java code

you may try to add `\` before `"`

I assume you are expecting something like this right?

```
String randomHtmlCode = " <DIV STYLE='font-family:\"Times New Roman\"'> ";
```

Comment: The problem I have is with decoding the `&quot;` within the String to be either a single or double quote depending on whether or not it's nested inside another encoded quote.